# Getting and displaying list of files in a directory according to a particular date using JAVA

Tags: java, unix, filtering, putty

I want to write a program, which when executed in PUTTY, asks for month and year as input and displays only the files having their modified(or created) date matching the inputs.
for ex- if user enters january 2013, then the output must be the files created or modified in jan'2013.
I am trying to use AgeFIleFilter but not getting the output for a particular date.

Anybody having a solution ?

Comment: There's a few different ways to get the last modified date. `java.io.File` or the Java NIO way with `FileAttributes`.

Comment: I am trying with this http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-filter-files-based-on-their-last-modified-dates.html
but it is not helping me get the exact particular date.
I want for a single date which user or i provides.